# Azure DevOps create environment - Access denied. {{USER}} needs Create permissions to perform the action

Tags: azure-devops

I am unable to create environemnts in an Azure DevOps project.

I have administrator access to the Organization, hence I granted my own user with all permissions in the project, but still when I attempt to create an environment I receive the following error:

```
Access denied. {{USER}} needs Create permissions to perform the action. For more information, contact the Azure DevOps Server administrator.
```

Answer (score 1):

I can also reproduce your issue on my side.

[image]

To solve the issue, please follow the steps below.

1. Navigate to the `Security` of the `Environments` like below.

[image]

2. Add your user account as a `Creator`, then you will be able to create the environment.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that helped me. I also had the problem of being a "Stakeholder" which could be solved by changing to "Basic":
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-pipeline-environments-unavailable-for-stakeh/1123916